# all wifi passwords gone after transferring system

Tags: networking, wireless, password

I broke the screen in my last netbook. After looking for replacements, I found buying a new netbook will cost little more than buying a replacement screen (and I'm getting uncracked case, new hinges, tab key not popping out, a working SD card reader, etc, etc, standard wear&tear of heavily used device), so I just bought the same model, and simply replaced the disk with my old one. From the point of view of the OS it's the same hardware, same configuration, the only thing different is serial numbers of components (other than hdd, unchanged) and some peripherals formerly broken now working.

It worked without a hitch - except for wifi passwords. All old networks I had ever connected to are saved where they were, but as I try to reconnect, I'm asked for their passwords. I entered the passwords to the networks I own, and it remembers the new passwords I enter just fine, but I need to ask for password at every cafe and office wherever I visit and used to connect with no hassle.

Can I restore the old passwords somehow?

I do have a backup of the system shortly before the transfer; also, the old netbook is still in working condition, just a large part of one corner of the screen invisible.

```
Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Linux 4.4.0-72-generic #93-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 31 14:07:41 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Its been a very long time since I have dont this (and my netbook long ago bit the dust), but I think if you copy the content of /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections from your old laptop to your new one, you should get your WiFi connections back

Comment: @NickSillito: The connections are there, it's just their passwords that vanished.

Comment: Are all the old connections listed in the file you copied?  /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/university and  /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/home, for example? What is in the files? It should read something like this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24434191/

Comment: @chili555: I found the reason, see the answer I posted. The files were untouched and are fine. MAC address changed though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I know what happened after looking at the connection list and findng a duplicate for every connection I reconnected to.

The connections all have a "Restrict to device" field set to my old MAC address. That means the connection will not be performed using the new wifi card. Changing this field to the new MAC should fix the problem.